# Log4j2 some logs are displayed on console

Tags: log4j2

Recently I have upgraded my project from Log4j1 to Log4j2. I have included below dependencies jars in my project. Some of the logs are going to console. In case of Log4j1 these logs are going to the rolling file. I am not sure what is the reason. Can you please help?

log4j-api-2.13.0.jar
log4j-core-2.13.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have left the log4j 1.x jar in your project. You should remove it, along with the log4 1.x configuration, and replace it with log4j-1.2-api-2.13.0.jar.